# Splitting messages with discord.js

Tags: split, discord.js

As the op stock command shows the list of txt files in a folder and because it goes beyond discord limit it cant send the message. How should i make it that it splits up in 2 messages? version is v12
Here's the code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const config = require('../config.json');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('op-stock')
        .setDescription('View op Gen stock'),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const opStock = await getStock(`${__dirname}/../op/`);

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(config.color.default)
            .setTitle(`${interaction.guild.name} Service Stock`)
            .setDescription(` Hello and welcome to **${interaction.guild.name}**!`)
            .setFooter(config.footer)
            .setImage(config.banner);

        if (opStock.length > 0) {
            const opStockInfo = await getServiceInfo(`${__dirname}/../op/`, opStock);
            embed.addField('op Services', opStockInfo, true);
        }

        
         interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed]});
       
    },
};

async function getStock(directory) {
    try {
        const files = await fs.readdir(directory);

        const stock = files.filter(file => file.endsWith('.txt'));
        return stock;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
        return [];
    }
}

async function getServiceInfo(directory, stock) {
    const info = [];
    for (const service of stock) {
        const serviceContent = await fs.readFile(`${directory}/${service}`, 'utf-8');
        const lines = serviceContent.split(/\r?\n/);
        info.push(`**${service.replace('.txt', '')}:** \`${lines.length}\``);
    }
    return info.join('\n');
}
```

i dont know how to split the messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would allow you up to 25 Fields if this is enough:

For DiscordJS v14 the .addFields method would look a bit different.

```
if (opStock.length > 0) {
    const opStockInfo = await getServiceInfo(`${__dirname}/../op/`, opStock);

    // Split opStockInfo into chunks of 1024 characters
    const chunkSize = 1024;
    for (let i = 0; i < opStockInfo.length; i += chunkSize) {
        const chunk = opStockInfo.substring(i, i + chunkSize);
        if(i == 0) embed.addField('op Services', chunk);
        else embed.addField(' ', chunk);
    }
}

interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
```

Comment: Nice to hear! Have fun working on your bot :)